# Why is this form input disappearing on a refresh?

Tags: forms, xhtml, input

I'm debugging a form and I find that when I refresh the page that one of the input elelments are set back to nothing (password) and the other two retain their value (text and checkbox).  This is in IE - is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this expected behavior?

Yes, password fields are not stored by default unless you instruct the browser to remember them. Normally when you submit a form containing as password fields the browser asks the user whether he wants to remember his login details for this site (behavior might vary between browsers and whether it is enabled or not).

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes. Browsers don't remember the values of password fields when you come back to a page because of the security risk it would pose.